# Exported variable has or is using private type TypeScript error

Tags: typescript

The following gets a rather cryptic TypeScript build error: `Exported variable 'res' has or is using private type 'Result'`.

```
interface Result {
    status: string;
    comment: string;
}

function runTest(st: any) {
    try {

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Failed test task: ' + err);
        console.log('Failed test task: ' + st.name);
        console.log(err.stack);
        var res: Result = {
            status: 'bad',
            comment: 'Nodejs exception: ' + err,
        };
        //saveTestResult(st, res);
    }
};

export function what() {};
```

It's all ok if either:

- Remove the try/catch
- Don't export the function `what`

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've found a bug in the compiler. You can work around it by moving the declaration of `res` (this doesn't change the behavior of the code):

```
function runTest(st: any) {
    var res: Result;
    try {

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Failed test task: ' + err);
        console.log('Failed test task: ' + st.name);
        console.log(err.stack);
        res = {
            status: 'bad',
            comment: 'Nodejs exception: ' + err,
        };
        //saveTestResult(st, res);
    }
};
```

Comment: Neat. Thanks! Is there an open issue or should I file one?